# Iterating over array created from subscribe function of Observable

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have this code that gets some data from a MongoDB and saves it in an array in my component.

```
this.laugService.getAllLaug().subscribe(laug => {
  this.laugs = laug; //save posts in array
});

this.laugs.array.forEach(element => {
  this.modelLaugs.push(new Laug(element.navn, element.beskrivelse))
});
```

After that i want to save this data to a different array, where i create new instances of my model "Laug". For this i am using a foreach loop, however i am getting an error when running this code:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 
'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

I am certain that i receive the data from the DB, however i am unsure why my array is undefined at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Your subscription is **asynchronous**. The *laugs* property may not be set when you are trying to iterate. Just put the forEach code inside the subscribe callback:

```
this.laugService.getAllLaug().subscribe(laug => {
   this.laugs = laug; //save posts in array

   if (this.laugs && this.laugs.array) {
       this.laugs.array.forEach(element => {
          this.modelLaugs.push(new Laug(element.navn, element.beskrivelse))
       });
   }
});
```